# How to get x, y coordinates of touch screen upon touch using Python kivy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I want to know the x,y coordinates of touch from a touch screen windows/Linux laptop for which kivy package would come in handy.

Since Kivy is an application builder, can its functionality be extended to get the entire screen's touch coordinates rather than from the widget application it hosts? I don't want it to show the black widget window and capture touch coordinates from there, rather it should fetch touch coordinates from the entire existing windows/Linux screen.

Or is there any other python package or code which can fetch me x, y coordinates of touch from the touch screen?

Following is the code tried to get coordinates of touch screen, but this code gives coordinates inside widget window. I want to get touch coordinates from the entire screen and the widget window shouldn't appear.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.core.window import Window
Window.fullscreen = True


class TouchInput(Widget=None):

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        print(f"X {touch.x} Y {touch.y}")


class SimpleKivy4(App):
    def build(self):
        return TouchInput()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    SimpleKivy4().run()
```

Comment: Please show sample code and what you have tried to do to answer this question.   There are various coordinate conversion calls available in Kivy.

Comment: Kivy probably doesn't expose this by default, but you could work it out by somehow querying the window size and adding the window pos.